# JNA DLL Function Call implementation

Tags: java, c++, pointers, dll, jna

I have tried and failed! first ill show you the c++ code im trying to imitate then the JNA java code i came up with (half of it works).

**C++ Code**

```
typedef struct 
{
    int DeviceType;
    int Handle;
    int NumberOfClients;
    int SerialNumber;
    int MaxAllowedClients;
} NeoDevice;

typedef int  (__stdcall *FINDNEODEVICES)(unsigned long DeviceTypes, NeoDevice *pNeoDevice, int *pNumDevices);

extern FINDNEODEVICES icsneoFindNeoDevices;

bool LoadDLLAPI(HINSTANCE &hAPIDLL){
     icsneoFindNeoDevices =    (FINDNEODEVICES) GetProcAddress(hAPIDLL, "icsneoFindNeoDevices");
}
```

**Java Code**

struct implementation...

```
public class NeoDevice extends Structure {

public volatile int DeviceType;
public volatile int Handle;
public volatile int NumberOfClients;
public volatile int SerialNumber;
public volatile int MaxAllowedClients;

public NeoDevice() {
    super();
}

protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("DeviceType", "Handle", "NumberOfClients", "SerialNumber", "MaxAllowedClients");
}

public NeoDevice(int DeviceType, int Handle, int NumberOfClients, int SerialNumber, int MaxAllowedClients) {
    super();
    this.DeviceType = DeviceType;
    this.Handle = Handle;
    this.NumberOfClients = NumberOfClients;
    this.SerialNumber = SerialNumber;
    this.MaxAllowedClients = MaxAllowedClients;
}

protected ByReference newByReference() { return new ByReference(); }
protected ByValue newByValue() { return new ByValue(); }
protected NeoDevice newInstance() { return new NeoDevice(); }

public static class ByReference extends NeoDevice implements Structure.ByReference {

};
public static class ByValue extends NeoDevice implements Structure.ByValue {

};
}
```

main class code...

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32");
icsneo40 n40 = icsneo40.INSTANCE;
NeoDevice.ByReference myDeviceByRef = new NeoDevice.ByReference();
int icsneoGetDLLVersion = n40.icsneoGetDLLVersion();
int iResult = n40.icsneoFindNeoDevices(65535, myDeviceByRef.getPointer(), NumDevices);
myDeviceByRef.read();
```

the function without params works fine and returns the integer it is supposed to.  the other one returns '1' which its supposed to but **the problem is** its also supposed to write to the fields of the struct i pass it but when i look at its fields, all are still zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNA updateStructureByReference() trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349037/jna-updatestructurebyreference-trouble)

Comment: You should edit your original question to clarify or update with new information.  Asking the same question in multiple places isn't helpful.