# Link third party dll to MY dll

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, jna

I am attempting to write some java code that will access the methods in a third party dll.  I have used JNA to try and map directly to it(i can call functions without structs as params) but I run into trouble when trying to access the fields of the structs after the function call (they were not updated). **So**, my brave new approach is to try and make my own dll, which takes primative variable types from my java code and in turn puts them into the appropriate structures to be passed to the third party dll.

I have c++ code that is linking fine with the third party dll but **my question is** how do i get my java code to work with this c++ code?  is it easiest to make the c++ code into a dll and if so how do i do that? (so turn this code into a dll itself. I am using visual studio 2012 and eclipse juno as my IDE's)

C++ code here (.cpp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Header.h"



FINDNEODEVICES icsneoFindNeoDevices;
GETDLLVERSION icsneoGetDLLVersion;

//extern int __declspec(dllimport) add(int a, int b);
bool LoadLibDLL(HINSTANCE &hAPIDLL){
    hAPIDLL = LoadLibrary(L"icsneo40.dll");
    icsneoGetDLLVersion = (GETDLLVERSION) GetProcAddress(hAPIDLL,                   "icsneoGetDLLVersion");
    icsneoFindNeoDevices =    (FINDNEODEVICES) GetProcAddress(hAPIDLL,              "icsneoFindNeoDevices");
    return true;
}

int main() {

    HINSTANCE icsneo40;
    bool success = LoadLibDLL(icsneo40);
    printf("Version #: %d\n", icsneoGetDLLVersion());
    int aray [5] = {600, 600, 600, 100, 600};
    int *p = aray;
    int num = 10;
    int lResult = icsneoFindNeoDevices(65545,p,&num);
    printf("Serial NUmber: %d\n", aray[3]);
    getchar();
    return 0;

 }
```

header(.h)

```
typedef int  (__stdcall *FINDNEODEVICES)(unsigned long DeviceTypes, int* myint, int *pNumDevices);
typedef int (__stdcall *GETDLLVERSION)(void);
extern FINDNEODEVICES icsneoFindNeoDevices;
extern GETDLLVERSION icsneoGetDLLVersion;
```

Comment: Turn it into a DLL and use JNI.

Comment: This is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349037/jna-updatestructurebyreference-trouble and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353245/jna-dll-function-call-implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try following a JNI tutorial like this one :

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

First, follow the tutorial to get Java methods that can call into C++ methods.
Then, modify the C++ methods to be similar to your code above, calling in to your third party DLL.